# how to do math in dict values are lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a problem I would like to add some math and add value to the list of dictionaries.

```
distance_travelled_by_each_node = {0: [0.0, 17.751, 594.24, 1394.3, 2042.442, 2086.694], 1: [0.0, 
              1870.058, 2299.614, 3584.593, 3838.359, 4638.419, 5286.561, 5368.107, 5792.431, 
              6285.873, 6500.971, 6524.217, 13880.759000000002, 14049.589000000002], 2: [0.0, 
              648.142, 729.6880000000001, 1154.0120000000002, 1647.4540000000002, 
              1862.5520000000001, 1885.7980000000002, 9242.340000000002, 9411.170000000002]}
```

code

```
arrival_time_at_each_node = {}
for i in range(len(distance_travelled_by_each_node)):
    for j in  range(len(distance_travelled_by_each_node[i])):
        arrival_time_at_each_node[i].append(distance_travelled_by_each_node[i][j]/20)
```

KeyError: 0

Output I expected:

```
arrival_time_at_each_node = {0:[0.0, 0.8875500000000001, 29.712, 69.715, 102.1221, 
      104.3347],1:[ 0.0, 93.5029, 114.9807, 179.22965, 191.91795, 231.92095, 
       264.32804999999996,268.40535, 289.62154999999996, 314.29364999999996, 325.04855, 
       326.21085, 694.0379500000001,702.47945],2:[ 0.0, 32.4071, 36.48440000000001, 
       57.70060000000001, 82.37270000000001, 93.1276,  94.28990000000002, 462.1170000000001, 
       470.5585000000001]}
```

Comment: You don't have a "list of dictionaries". You have a dictionary whose item values are lists.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a dictionary not a list ! You can obtain first the different keys and then the values. Also do not forget to start the list inside the new dictionary.

This should do :

```
arrival_time_at_each_node = {}
for key in distance_travelled_by_each_node.keys():
    arrival_time_at_each_node[key] = []
    for j, value in  enumerate(distance_travelled_by_each_node[key]):
        arrival_time_at_each_node[key].append(value/20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
arrival_time_at_each_node = {k: [x/20 for x in v] for k,v in distance_travelled_by_each_node.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility, use a `defaultdict` instead of an ordinary `dict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
arrival_time_at_each_node = defaultdict(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a `KeyError` because of this line.

```
arrival_time_at_each_node[i].append(distance_travelled_by_each_node[i][j]/20)
```

Because there's no key `0` in `arrival_time_at_each_node` when you are trying to append to its value.

However you could try this way.

```
distance_travelled_by_each_node = {0: [0.0, 17.751, 594.24, 1394.3, 2042.442, 2086.694], 1: [0.0, 
              1870.058, 2299.614, 3584.593, 3838.359, 4638.419, 5286.561, 5368.107, 5792.431, 
              6285.873, 6500.971, 6524.217, 13880.759000000002, 14049.589000000002], 2: [0.0, 
              648.142, 729.6880000000001, 1154.0120000000002, 1647.4540000000002, 
              1862.5520000000001, 1885.7980000000002, 9242.340000000002, 9411.170000000002]}

arrival_time_at_each_node = {}

for i,v in distance_travelled_by_each_node.items():
    arrival_time_at_each_node[i] = [x/20 for x in v]
    
print(arrival_time_at_each_node)
```

```
{0: [0.0, 0.8875500000000001, 29.712, 69.715, 102.1221, 104.3347], 1: [0.0, 93.5029, 114.9807, 179.22965, 191.91795, 231.92095, 264.32804999999996, 268.40535, 289.62154999999996, 314.29364999999996, 325.04855, 326.21085, 694.0379500000001, 702.47945], 2: [0.0, 32.4071, 36.48440000000001, 57.70060000000001, 82.37270000000001, 93.1276, 94.28990000000002, 462.1170000000001, 470.5585000000001]}
```